# Fetching data from API and Displaying response data into a Data grid

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Error trying to fetch data from an API which is then passed to a DataGrid.

The data is returned as follows:

```
{
  data: [{
      type: 'PropertyDamage',
      id: '100',
      attributes: {
        identification_number: '3931',
        damage_date: '2021-04-29',
        report_date: '2021-06-26'
      }
    },
    {
      type: 'PropertyDamage',
      id: '101',
      attributes: {
        identification_number: '3839',
        damage_date: '2021-01-21',
        report_date: '2021-08-25'
      }
    },
    {
      type: 'PropertyDamage',
      id: '102',
      attributes: {
        identification_number: '3735',
        damage_date: '2021-04-25',
        report_date: '2021-10-29'
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

The component that is handling the fetching of data as well as rendering the DataGrid:

```
const columns = [
  { field: "id", headerName: "ID" },
  { field: "type", headerName: "TYPE" },
];

const Dashboard = () => {

  const [propertydamages, setPropertyDamages] = useState([]);

  useEffect(() => {
    const url = "URL";
    fetch(url, {
      method: "GET",
      withCredentials: true,
      headers: {
        "X-API-Key": "API Key",
      },
    })
      .then((response) => response.json())
      .then((json) => {
        setPropertyDamages(json);
      })
      .catch(function (error) {
        console.log(error);
      });
  }, []);

  return (
    <Box m="20px">
      {/* Data Grid */}
      <DataGrid rows={propertydamages} columns={columns} />
    </Box>
  );
};
```

The error being logged to the console on render:

```
index.js:1272 Warning: Failed prop type: Invalid prop `rows` of type `object` supplied to `ForwardRef(DataGrid)`, expected an array.
        at div
        at http://localhost:3000/static/js/0.chunk.js:942:73
        at Box (http://localhost:3000/static/js/0.chunk.js:69597:74)
        at div
        at http://localhost:3000/static/js/0.chunk.js:942:73
        at Box (http://localhost:3000/static/js/0.chunk.js:69597:74)
        at Dashboard (http://localhost:3000/static/js/main.chunk.js:373:77)
        at RenderedRoute (http://localhost:3000/static/js/0.chunk.js:153998:27)
        at Routes (http://localhost:3000/static/js/0.chunk.js:154437:24)
        at main
        at div
        at InnerThemeProvider (http://localhost:3000/static/js/0.chunk.js:68080:72)
        at ThemeProvider (http://localhost:3000/static/js/0.chunk.js:67042:24)
        at ThemeProvider (http://localhost:3000/static/js/0.chunk.js:68098:24)
        at App (http://localhost:3000/static/js/main.chunk.js:51:72)
        at Router (http://localhost:3000/static/js/0.chunk.js:154367:30)
        at BrowserRouter (http://localhost:3000/static/js/0.chunk.js:152656:23)
```

I tried changing the data into different formats but it was not working.

Comment: What is the error?

Comment: Check your placing of the `useEffect` dependency array. To me it looks like it's in the wrong place. It should come after the next `{` . `useEffect(( )=>{},[])` . You may be in an infinite loop

Comment: Based on your update, the answer is here `type object supplied to ForwardRef(DataGrid), expected an array.` Best to check that your data is an array and not something like `{results:[//data]}`

Comment: @RyanZeelie Yes, It was running in an infinite loop. I changed the positioning of the useEffect dependency array. Thank you for your help. But still data is not appearing in the data grid

Comment: @evolutionxbox index.js:1272 Warning: Failed prop type: Invalid prop `rows` of type `object` supplied to `ForwardRef(DataGrid)`, expected an array. This is the error

Comment: Try using `<DataGrid rows = {propertydamages.data}` ?

Comment: @evolutionxbox Tried that as well. Unfortunately, it does not work.

Comment: `<DataGrid rows = {propertydamages.data}` wont work because data is undefined initially. What you need to do is set the data correctly here :  `setPropertyDamages(json.data)`

Comment: @RyanZeelie Thank you so much. It works properly now. Setting data properly is the solution to this problem.

Answer (score 1):

For those coming across this post. The MUI DataGrid takes an array of objects in the `rows` prop

```
<DataGrid rows={propertydamages} columns={columns} />
```

Setting this prop to `null` `undefined` or an `object` will result in an error and your component will not render. If you are using state to populate the rows, be sure that the initial value is an empty array `[]` and that the data being receieved is in fact going to be an array. How you do your checks is up to you but I would highly recommend that the state does not get updated unless the update is going to result in an array